# Is there any easier way to evaluate $(A^{-1}+λI)^{-1}$ than directly? (A is a symmetric real matrix.)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given a symmetric real matrix $A$, is there any potentially easier way to evaluate $(A^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}$ than directly?

(I'm hoping the matrix inversions can be avoided somehow.)

Background: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3664647/86969

2nd prize edit: How about if both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are available?

### Edit

Given that $A$ is symmetric, we have $A=R^{-1}DR$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $R$ is an orthogonal matrix (e.g. rotation).

So FWIW the expression is equivalent to

$$
(A^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}=
((R^{-1}DR)^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}
=(RD^{-1}R^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}
=(R(D^{-1}+\lambda R^{-1}IR)R^{-1})^{-1}
=R(D^{-1}+\lambda R^{-1}IR)^{-1}R^{-1}
=R(D^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}R^{-1}
$$

Comment: You may want to quote the trxt in your link in case it gets broken

Comment: What do you mean by easier? In less than O(n^3)? Or you want to avoid inversions due to concerns of numerical stability? If the latter, you can diagonalize A.

Comment: At the first glance, it seems that you might be interested in the idea of *matrix Taylor expansion*. A seemingly nice "exposition" can be found here http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/2291/1/paper.pdf.

Comment: For sufficiently small $\lambda$, we have the infinite series
$$
(A^{-1} + \lambda I)^{-1} = A(I + \lambda A)^{-1} = A - \lambda A^2 + \lambda^2 A^3 - \lambda^3 A^4 + \cdots.
$$
This sum converges iff $\lambda < \lambda_{\max}(A)^{-1}$.

Comment: @AmitHochman Yes; a more time-efficient algorithm than matrix inversion. Ideally an expression that doesn't require any matrix inversion.

Comment: If $\lambda=0$ everything is trivial. So WLOG $\lambda \neq 0$. Note that $$(I+\lambda A)^{-1}=I- \lambda (A^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}$$ So any formula without inversion would give a non-inversion formula for calculating $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$. Now, since any symmetric $B$ can be written in the form $I-\lambda A$ for some $A$, this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @N.S. Care to put that in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $\lambda=0$ we have 
$$(A^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}=A$$

Now, if $\lambda \neq 0$, a simple computation yields
$$
(I+\lambda A)^{-1}=I- \lambda (A^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}
$$

Assume by contradiction that there is a formula for calculating $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$ without using iversion.

Then, for each symmertic matrix $B$, setting $A=\frac{1}{\lambda} (B-I)$ we can calculate
$$B^{-1}=(I+\lambda A)^{-1}=I- \lambda (A^{-1}+\lambda I)^{-1}$$
without using inversion.